# Show a loading gif while iframe page content loads

Tags: html, iframe, loading, show, gif

I searched and tried various solutions to what I'm trying to achieve, to no avail...

I'm working on a photography website which has a high volume of images loading in an iframe, which takes a bit of time to load.  I want to show a loading gif image in the iframe until the images have finished loading.

Here is the website in question, http://www.chriszachary.com/portfolio

I'm using a javascript motion gallery to allow the user to control image scrolling with their mouse.  The images do not scroll until the page is fully loaded.  To help minimize confusion, I figured a loading gif image would be more efficient, but I can't pull it off.  If you click any of the portfolio categories (wedding, engagement, portrait) you'll notice a significant wait time to load the images.

If anyone could let me know how to achieve this within the iframe, please let me know.  And if you could be specific on what code to use and where, I'm a novice :|

Thanks in advance, looking forward to an answer :)

Answer (score 32):

Replace the `IFRAME` tag in that page with below HTML. The `IFRAME` is covered with a `DIV` where the loading image (or any image) is found. The image is at the center of the `DIV` area and its size can be up to 950x633 pixels. When the `IFRAME` page is loaded, the loading image will be hidden.

What you need to change is the image URL for your site. You might also want to change the `DIV` background color (currently set to `#FFF`).

```
<style>
#loadImg{position:absolute;z-index:999;}
#loadImg div{display:table-cell;width:950px;height:633px;background:#fff;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
</style>
<div id="loadImg"><div><img src="loading.gif" /></div></div>
<iframe border=0 name=iframe src="html/wedding.html" width="950" height="633" scrolling="no" noresize frameborder="0" onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

Comment: Everything about this works for me EXCEPT - the gif ends up sitting on top of my iframe and never goes away. Any suggestions?

Comment: And to answer my own comment, I adjusted the z-index on #loadImg to -1 and added a div wrapper around the iframe with a z-index of 999. Not sure if that is the most elegant way to handle it, but it seems to be working on my site.

Comment: Your answer is good BUT you need to give the iframe an ID or class add some css to it as well as well otherwise the loading is on top of the iframe e.g:

iframe.myclass {position:relative; z-index:1000}

Comment: NEVER use z-index: 1000 please

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to trigger when iframe is loaded

```
$('#iframeTest').on("load", function () {
    console.log('iframe loaded'); //replace with code to hide loader
});
```