# Show loading gif every time iframe loads a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I would like a loading GIF is displayed over an iframe in the parent window whenever a new page is loaded in the iframe. I've seen solutions for questions like this, but they only seem to work for the default page. Once the user navigates away from that page in the iframe, the loading GIF won't show up.

Is this possible using either JavaScript or jQuery? I've tried other solutions on Stack Overflow with no luck.

Comment: Hard to understand your problem. What do you mean "When the user navigates away from the page in the iframe"? Oh and people are going to ask you "What have you done"  or the possible "Show us what you've tried"?

Comment: "When the user navigates away from the page in the iframe" aka when the user clicks away from the iframe's  default page. What I have tried is the solutions already on Stack Overflow for similar questions. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136788/show-a-loading-gif-while-iframe-page-content-loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your frame will always be on the same domain as the parent window, you can register the `onbeforeunload` event handler on the iframe `contentWindow` to detect navigating away.

Example:

```
var iframe = // create or get iframe, make sure no src parameter at first
var unload = function(){
    // show loading gif here
};

var load = function(){
    // hide loading gif here

    iframe.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = unload;
    iframe.onload = load;
};

unload();
iframe.onload = load;
iframe.src = "your url here";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnausxac/1/

Note: Do not register the `onbeforeunload` event within the iframe using something like

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){/* ... */} // BAD
```

This will overwrite your parent event handler. If you need to detect the event in the iframe then set up some sort of callback with the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with `iframes` which have empty `src` and store the target in another property

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="gif-hidden"></div>
    <iframe class="myframe" src="" attr-link="https://google.com/" attr-first="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then when the **page loaded** successfully, start the animation and set the `src` values

`.gif-hidden` should have the `display:none` or `opacity:0` property, while `.gif` is visible.

```
$('.gif-hidden').removeClass('gif-hidden').addClass('gif');
$('.myframe').attr('src',$('.myframe').attr('attr-link'));
```

Also add an event listener to disable the animation once the `iframe` is loaded at the first time

```
$('.myframe').load(function(){
     if($(this).attr('attr-first') == "true")
     {
         $(this).attr('attr-first','false');
         $(this).prev().hide();
     }
}
```

Didn't tested, but should work.

Comment: I don't think this will show up every time a page inside the iframe is loading, will it?

Comment: You asked for a solution that only shows the animation at the first load.

"Once the user navigates away from that page in the iframe, the loading GIF won't show up."

Comment: No, what I meant by that is that when trying to other solutions, the loading GIF wouldn't show up. I __want__ it to show up.